# Django - 405 POST not allowed

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a form like so:

```
{% extends "interface/base.html" %}
{% load subscribertags %}

{% block title %}{{ object }}{% endblock %}
{% block center %}



<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Редактирование меню <small>{% operator_name object.operator %}: {{ object }} ({{ object.slug }})</small></h1>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="itemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="itemModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

        <h4 class="modal-title" id="itemModalTitle">Добавить пункт</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
                <label for="item_name">Действие</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="action">
                  <option value="">----------</option>
                  {% for value, action in actions %}
                      <option value="{{ value }}">{{ action }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
          </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input id='is_hidden' type="checkbox" name='is_hidden' > Спрятать
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input id='allow_back' type="checkbox" name='allow_back' > Пункт назад
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="label">Метка</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="label" placeholder="Название метки" name='slug'>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="params">Доп параметры</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="params" placeholder="Дополнительные параметры" name='params'></textarea>
       </div>
       {% for code, language in languages %}
          <div class="form-group">
              <h5>{{ language }}</h5>
              {% if code = object.default_language %}
                <label for="text">Текст</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Текст" name='text'>
                <label for="result_text">Текст результата</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="result_text" placeholder="Текст результата" name='result_text'>
              {% else %}
                <label for="text-{{ code }}">Текст</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text-{{ code }}" placeholder="Текст" name='text-{{ code }}'>
                <label for="result_text-{{ code }}">Текст результата</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="result_text-{{ code }}" placeholder="Текст результата" name='result_text-{{ code }}'>
              {% endif %}
         </div>
       {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
        <button type="subbmit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </form>
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="tree">
    {% if object.item_set.count %}
        <ul>
            {% with object.item_set.all.0 as item %}
                {% include "interactive/interface/menu_item.html" %}
            {% endwith %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

SECOND PART:

{% load interactivetags %}
<li class="element-interactive-item{% if not item.is_visible %} i-hidden{% endif %}">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{  item.params }}" class='name'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-{% item_icon item %}"></i> ({{ item.id }}) {{ item }} {% if item.slug %}({{ item.slug }}){% endif %}

        <a class='tool item-tool'  data-values='{% item_to_json item %}' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemModal" data-label="Редактировать: {{ item }}" href="#" data-href="{% url "interactive.views.item_update" pk=item.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a class='tool item-tool' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemModal" data-label="Добавить пункт" href="#" <data-href="{% url "interactive.views.item_create" pk=object.pk parent_pk=item.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>



        {% if item.is_leaf_node and not  item.is_root_node%}
        <a class='tool confirm' href="{% url "interactive.views.item_delete" pk=item.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
        {% endif %}

        <a class='tool confirm' href="{% url "interactive.views.item_up" pk=item.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i></a>
        <a class='tool confirm' href="{% url "interactive.views.item_down" pk=item.pk %}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i></a>

    </span>
    <ul>
            {% for item in item.get_children %}
                {% include "interactive/interface/menu_item.html" %}
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I hit the Save/Сохранить button data isn't updated in the database for this form and I get

```
"POST /interactive/1/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

Code that handles the request:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from interactive.models import Menu, Item
from interactive.forms import UpdateItemForm
from interface.views import InterfaceMixin
from interactive.processors import ProcessorManager
from subscribers.models import Subscriber
from languages.models import Translate


class MenuList(InterfaceMixin, ListView):
    model = Menu
    name = u'Интерактивные меню'

index = MenuList.as_interface_view(template_name='interactive/interface/index.html')


class MenuItem(InterfaceMixin, DetailView):
    """ Редактирование интерактивного меню """
    model = Menu

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        kwargs['actions'] = ProcessorManager.actions()
        kwargs['languages'] = Subscriber.LANGUAGES
        return super(MenuItem, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

menu = MenuItem.as_interface_view(item=MenuList, template_name='interactive/interface/item.html')


class ItemMixin:

    @classmethod
    def update_language(cls, attribute, text, context):
        if text:
            o, _ = Translate.objects.get_or_create(attribute=attribute, **context)
            o.text = text
            o.save()




class CreateItemView(ItemMixin, InterfaceMixin, CreateView):

    menu = None
    parent = None
    model = Item
    form_class = UpdateItemForm
    auth = False


    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse("interactive.views.menu", kwargs={'pk': self.menu.pk})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


        pk = kwargs.get('pk')


        parent_pk = kwargs.get('parent_pk')
        self.menu = Menu.objects.get(pk=pk)
        self.parent = Item.objects.get(pk=parent_pk)
        return super(CreateItemView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def form_valid(self, form):


        form.instance.menu = self.menu
        form.instance.insert_at(self.parent, position='last-child')
        form.instance.save()
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(form.instance)

        for code, _ in Subscriber.LANGUAGES:
            text = self.request.POST.get('text-%s' % code)
            result_text = self.request.POST.get('result_text-%s' % code)
            context = dict(content_type=ct, object_id=form.instance.pk, language=code, operator=self.menu.operator)
            self.update_language('text', text, context)
            self.update_language('result_text', result_text, context)
        return super(CreateItemView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(CreateItemView, self).form_valid(form)



item_create = CreateItemView.as_view()

class UpdateItemView(ItemMixin, InterfaceMixin, UpdateView):
    """ Изменение пункта меню """

    model = Item
    form_class = UpdateItemForm
    auth = False



    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("interactive.views.menu", kwargs={'pk': self.object.menu.pk})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.object)
        for code, _ in Subscriber.LANGUAGES:
            text = self.request.POST.get('text-%s' % code)
            result_text = self.request.POST.get('result_text-%s' % code)
            context = dict(content_type=ct, object_id=self.object.pk, language=code)
            self.update_language('text', text, context)
            self.update_language('result_text', result_text, context)
        return super(UpdateItemView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(UpdateItemView, self).form_valid(form)

item_update = UpdateItemView.as_view()


class DeleteItemView(InterfaceMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Item
    auth = False


    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse("interactive.views.menu", kwargs={'pk': self.object.menu.pk})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

item_delete = DeleteItemView.as_view()


class UpDownItemVew(DetailView):
    action = None
    model = Item
    auth = False 



    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        item = self.get_object()
        if self.action == 'left':
            other = item.get_previous_sibling()
        else:
            other = item.get_next_sibling()

        item.move_to(other, position=self.action)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("interactive.views.menu", kwargs={'pk': item.menu.pk}))

item_up = UpDownItemVew.as_view(action='left')
item_down = UpDownItemVew.as_view(action='right')
```

URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
'interactive.views',
    (r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<parent_pk>\d+)/additem/$', "item_create"),
    (r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', "item_delete"),
    (r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/up/$', "item_up"),
    (r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/down/$', "item_down"),
    (r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', "item_update"),
    (r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', "menu"),
    (r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

This code perfectly work on a production server, but wasn't uploaded by me and uses nginx as http server.
I am running it on local server using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: given url is dispatech by the `menu` route so... could you show us its code?

Comment: Since you don't supply an `action` attribute in your `<form>` element, it appears you're sending the `POST` request to `/interactive/1`, which is the "menu" view. The latter doesn't appear to handle `POST` requests. Perhaps you need to send it to `item_update` or `item_create`?

Comment: It need to be sent to `item_create` but it doesn't.

Comment: modify `<form>` to point to that route then: `<form action="{% url "item_create" %}`